# SQL Joins + Counts

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join

I've quite stuck in building query, which is to count appearences of special cases

I have:

```
teachers {id, email, first_name, last_name,...}
faculties {id, name}
pupils {id, name, teacher_id} //every pupil has their own curator
faculties_teachers {id, teacher_id, faculty_id}
```

The query tries to check the integrity of the data. There should be no duplicates.

I need to get a query with amount of pupils per teacher on faculty.

This query worked absolutely fine until I added my attempt to count distinct pupils per faculties (they are indeed, unique in my case :))

```
SELECT u1.id, u2.id, u1.owner, u2.owner, u1.email, u1.first_name, u2.last_name, u1.name_of_site, faculties_teachers.faculty_id, faculties.name, 
      (SELECT COUNT( pupils.* ) FROM pupils as p WHERE faculties.id = pupils.faculty_id)
FROM `teachers` AS u1
JOIN `teachers` AS u2 ON u1.email = u2.email
JOIN `faculties_teachers` AS ft ON u1.id = ft.teacher_id
JOIN `faculties` ON faculties.id = ft.faculty_id
JOIN `pupils` ON faculties.id = pupils.faculty_id
WHERE u1.id < u2.id
ORDER BY `u1`.`id` ASC
```

Comment: What are you joining `teachers` twice?  Sample data and desired results would help, as well as an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Gordon, 
actually we had several issues in our system:
- improper 'teacher delete' function, which erased only teachers, without dependencies (in faculties_teachers). 
As a result, when someone wants to get all the teachers on a faculty, 
they see a lot of empty rows, what is quite wrong.
- improper "import teachers to faculty" function... which doubled teachers' data....
So in 1 query I wanted to "kill them all" :)
Right now I have some enormous amount of work, but later I'll fix this question.
I see it as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hehe - thanks to my colleague

```
SELECT u1.id, u2.id, u1.owner, u2.owner, u1.email, u1.first_name, u2.last_name, u1.name_of_site, faculties_teachers.faculty_id, faculties.name, COALESCE(pupil_counts_by_faculties.pupil_cnt, 0) AS pupil_cnt
FROM `teachers` AS u1
JOIN `teachers` AS u2 ON u1.email = u2.email
JOIN `faculties_teachers` ON u1.id = faculties_teachers.urid
JOIN `faculties` ON faculties.id = faculties_teachers.faculty_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT `faculty_id`, COUNT(*) AS pupil_cnt
   FROM `pupils`
   GROUP BY `faculty_id`
) AS pupil_counts_by_faculties ON `faculties`.`id` = pupil_counts_by_faculties.faculty_id
WHERE u1.id < u2.id
```